# dates change after combining vectors of dates in R

Tags: r, date, vector, lubridate

I'm trying to combine two vectors of dates into a single vector. I have been using dates with the lubridate package.

First I create two vectors of dates:

```
library(lubridate)

mydate <- mdy("04/01/2016")
mydate_range <- mydate + (1:12)*months(1)

anotherdate_range <- mdy("05/01/2017") + (1:12)*months(1)
```

Inspecting mydate_range and anotherdate_range these seem to have worked fine.

But then when I try to combine these into one vector things get weird.

```
combineddates <- c(mydate_range, anotherdate_range)
combineddates
[1] "2016-04-30 19:00:00 CDT" "2016-05-31 19:00:00 CDT" "2016-06-30 19:00:00 CDT"
```

The first date of combineddates is now "2016-04-30". Before I combined them using the c() function the first date of mydate_range was "2016-05-01".

Not sure why this changed. How should I join these date vectors?

Comment: How are you ending up with a `POSIXct/lt` datetime from combining two `Date` objects? I can't replicate your example.

Comment: I agree with @thelatemail, can't replicate. works fine for me, I get `Date[1:24], format: "2016-05-01" "2016-06-01" "2016-07-01" "2016-08-01" "2016-09-01" ...`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the date change is the conversion due to time zone adjustments.  2016-04-30 19:00:00 CDT is the same as 2016-05-01 GMT.  Most likely your initial sequence was in GMT and somewhere along the way it got converted to local time.
I find it best to define the time zone in your initial definition and it should stay consistent throughout.

Comment: While this is the likely reason, as far as I know R's basic `Date` objects don't have a timezone associated with them. Somewhere along the line, OP has converted things to a datetime, probably a `POSIXct` object I'm guessing.

Comment: I have not used lubridate enough to understand it well. But ymd will return a POSIX object if there a time segment attached.

Comment: Actually I see the time zone changing after combining date vectors even though the time zone is specified in the original two and is the same. It is also picking up a time stamp. I am using lubridate, which you should definitely use, but even lubridate is not perfect. My quick workaround is convert to character, combine the vectors, convert back to date with correct time zone and no time stamp re-specified. This answer seems like an obvious soltuion, but unfortunately things with dates are never obvious.